# How to read nested elements from an XmlReader in .NET?

Tags: .net, f#, xmlreader

I am trying to get the maximum performance when reading (relatively) large xml files using the XmlReader class.

Below is an outline of my current (working) code:

```
let reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)

while reader.Read() do

    if reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name = "dimension" then
        ()
    elif reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name = "c" then

        target <- reader.GetAttribute("r") |> Address.Parse

        use subReader = reader.ReadSubtree()

        while subReader.Read() do
            if subReader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element && subReader.Name = "f" then
                ()
            elif subReader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element && subReader.Name = "v" then
                ()
```

My concern is that the allocation of the `subReader` object is showing up in my performance profiling as taking up a large amount of time and I was wondering if there was a more performant way of achieving the same thing - namely reading the two **simple/non-recursive** elements "f" and "v" at the current node into some sort of data structure for subsequent parsing.

Comment: Perhaps XPATH queries on [XPathDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument) could work better? I don't know if it'll be more efficient, but in general this is something that can only be measured, never predicted...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks. I am looking for something that uses XmlReader because (1) that's the generally recommended approach for best performance and (2) streaming keeps memory usage low. I just figure that once you have a small "leaf of the overall" document there may be a better way to read it into memory and get what you need.

Comment: IIRC, XPathDocument doesn't load the entire document into memory either (or could it be one of the other implementations of `IXpathNavigatable`?)

Comment: Can you post some example data. Obviously not the full document but something that looks like it.

Comment: Have you tried `ReadToDescendant`?

Comment: Consider taking this to CodeReview. Stack overflow is more for solving problems, not optimizing.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/